# Quality gates are getting displayed as a blank page in sonar 4.3.3

Tags: sonarqube

We had a back up of our sonar db and for some reason we had to restore it back on the same host but this time with a different ORACLE_SID. Now after restoring we tried couple of upload and accessing the various dashboard on sonar and things were seamlessly working as earlier.

Its only when we try to access Quality gates (url:port/sonar/quality_gates) a blank screen appears with a pop up saying "default_error_message".

Please guide what wrong in this case ?

I tried accessing Quality_gates and QUALITY_GATE_CONDITIONS and able to see data in back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to upgrade to latest LTS of SonarQube (currently 6.7) in order to get feedbacks, as 4.3.3 is more than 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was encountered as we tried migrating to 4.5.7 and some how our in house plugin's started breaking.Working on their compatibility as of now.My problem in this case got resolved once I cleared by browser cache and things were back to normal.